# Edit Read Only PDF Form

Tags: package-management, conversion

I wish to change a PDF doc which I can read only.  I need to add details to this document.  Please, in SIMPLE words, how do I do this?  I have very little expertise!!  Thank you

Comment: If it's "read only" and possibly password protected, you can't make changes.

Comment: Close voters! Note: Answered.

Answer (score 2):

This seems a simple task provided that you have permissions to print the PDF, you can simply [print a copy to a file](https://askubuntu.com/questions/99269/how-do-i-print-a-pdf-file/397270) that you do have permission to edit. One method of editing that comes to mind would be to open the copy you made in `gimp`. How you would go about this depends on what exactly you intend to do, but gimp is very powerful and fairly straightforward to use. You can find [tutorials on usage](https://www.gimp.org/tutorials/) that should help you. There is a tutorial covering this exact topic [here.](http://www.troubleshooters.com/linux/gimp/gimppdf.htm)

Here's a quick once over of the process.

1 Launch `gimp`

2 open the PDF

3 Select Tools -> Text (to add text) or whichever of the many tools available that meets your requirements.

If it's text,

Draw text box and click in it to type the text you want as in the example below.

[image: gimp-pdf]

Select the font and size you want from the shadow box above the text box you drew and then type the text you want into the box.

When you've completed your editing you can simply select File -> Export and choose a new name and a location you have permission to write in for your modified PDF file.

If you have something besides adding text in mind, `gimp` has a [wide selection of tools available,](https://docs.gimp.org/en/gimp-tools.html) but you probably don't need to know them all in order to accomplish your task.

Answer (score 2):

I think you can do what you want with **`xournal`**.

Install

```
sudo apt install xournal
```

Run

```
xournal document.pdf
```

and edit alias overlay text or graphics.

You can save the overlay in a small file, and you can export the result as a new pdf file.

Example:

```
xournal mkUSB-quick-start-manual-12.pdf
```

[image]