# Foxit PDF reader crashed when try to comment or highlight text

Tags: pdf, foxitreader

Foxit reader closed when I try to highlight text (open highlights, write comment, etc) in any PDF file.

Reinstall does not fix the problem. *(The Foxit-reader version is: FoxitReader.enu.setup.2.4.1.0609(r08f07f8).x64.run )*

the log error in  /var/log/syslog/apport.log file is

```
ERROR: apport (pid 20609) Sun Jan 21 15:37:40 2018: executable: /home/mostafa/opt/foxit/foxitreader/FoxitReader (command line "/home/mostafa/opt/foxit/foxitreader/FoxitReader")
ERROR: apport (pid 20609) Sun Jan 21 15:37:40 2018: executable does not belong to a package, ignoring
```

Is there any way to find the problem and solve it?

Thanks for any help.

---

- for first comment

  1. Difference of highlighted text showed in Evince (Right in figure) vs
     other PDF readers (here is Adobe reader) [Fig: Evince vs Adobe reader](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oq2pC.png)
  2. Foxit reader shows texts better than other at least adobe reader and
     evince. [Fig: evince vs Foxit reader for reading some text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YCTtt.png) (also, you can test this PDF file from [here](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/M_R_Ashwin_Kishore/post/How_can_I_build_a_slab_using_VESTA_for_surface_calculations/attachment/59d6459979197b80779a0b2e/AS:454022458023936@1485258797029/download/ETasci_2013_SurfacePreparationHowTo.pdf). )

Comment: Is there some specific reason that you are trying to use FoxitReader rather than the supported and installed by default in Ubuntu `evince` ? To the best of my knowledge PDF Readers don't typically allow for editing of documents.

Comment: Assuming that you are attempting to edit a PDF you might find [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/997682/edit-read-only-pdf-form/997714#997714) useful.

Comment: yes, the evince doesn't show the highlighted text color correctly (I will put a figure in my question.).  I always used adobe reader (it has some features that does not exist in any other program (Ex. single hot keys, snapshot (with high resolution , etc ...)  . Only Okular has some features (but it does not comfortable). so I use Foxit reader that has the most of the features that I need.) ...... also Foxit reader shows the text better than adobe reader.)

Comment: @ElderGeek, Thanks for your suggestion. I will check it later.

Comment: I would ask here http://forums.foxitsoftware.com/, either they answer your question or they forwarded to the technical team as a bug report or here https://www.foxitsoftware.com/company/contact.php or here http://tickets.foxitsoftware.com/create.php and there are alternatives  https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/2557/maintained-ubuntu-pdf-reader-with-text-highlighting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After help of Foxit Reader's technical team, the solution was found. It seems the problem occured after updating the language packages (from language support of Ubuntu system setting).

The solution: Going to ‍`/home/mostafa/.local/share/Foxit Software/`  address (use your home name instead of `mostafa`), and deleting the "Foxit Reader" folder. Then, if needed, reinstall the Foxit reader.

Also, if you need to save the log file, it is the way from Foxit Reader's technical team: .... "Please open Foxit Reader, go to Help>About Foxit Reader, click on Foxit Reader text three times continuously, you will get the directory for saving the log file."  (notice: I clicked multiple times on it, to this open)

*I am appreciative of Lyndi Wu from the technical team and @Lynob.*

Answer (score 1):

One possible solution is to disable internet related functions, including

1. "Connected PDF" :

`Edit -> Preferences -> General -> Disable Connected PDF features`

2. AutoUpdate:

`Edit -> Preferences -> Updater -> Do not check for updates`

One of the posts on their online forum seems to point to connected PDF, and foxitdrive etc.

It's just a guess, but disabling the above seems to work so far.

Also, according the [Foxit](https://forums.foxitsoftware.com/forum/portable-document-format-pdf-tools/foxit-reader/183039-foxit-reader-freeze-on-ubuntu-20-04#post183041), current support for Linux is up to 16.10:

> Our existing version of Foxit Reader for Linux's OS requirements are
> as follows:
>
> Ubuntu Desktop 14.04 ~ 16.10
>
> Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server 6.x (64-bit) ~ 7.x
>
> ...
>
> So it doesn't support Ubuntu 20.04.
>
> In addition,due to human resources limited,our developers have stopped
> fixing issues and developing new features for Foxit Reader for Linux.

So, the crash may well be a consequence of that.