# What are some great PDF editors for Linux?

Tags: software-recommendation, pdf

Hi I am looking for some great PDF editors besides Qoppa Software's PDF Studio I have already found, which is quite affordable. Are their any other ones more affordable for Ubuntu?

Comment: **LibreOffice Draw** will take care of most of my PDF editing needs. It is very affordable, it is Free. See: https://askubuntu.com/a/99788/43926

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to Edit PDFs?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162037/how-to-edit-pdfs) and [Which programs can I use to edit PDF files?](https://askubuntu.com/q/16652/)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Which programs can I use to edit PDF files?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/16652/which-programs-can-i-use-to-edit-pdf-files)

Answer (score 15):

### To change texts/annotate/insert images:

---

Try [Xournal++](https://xournalpp.github.io/), which can used as an annotating tool. You can write on PDFs with mouse and digital pen, erase text and images, insert text, insert images, insert equations with LaTeX, and do many more things.

[image: xournalpp]

To install it in Ubuntu 18.04-21.10, you can use the [Xournal++ stable](https://launchpad.net/%7Eapandada1/+archive/ubuntu/xournalpp-stable) PPA

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:apandada1/xournalpp
sudo apt update
sudo apt install xournalpp
```

In Ubuntu 22.04 and above, you can install it from the repositories (although the PPA still hosts updated versions).

```
sudo apt install xournalpp
```

You can also use the [snap](https://snapcraft.io/xournalpp) and [flatpak](https://flathub.org/apps/details/com.github.xournalpp.xournalpp) versions, but they may have issues with LaTeX.

---

### To reorder/remove/add/rotate pages:

---

You can use PDF Arranger.

```
sudo apt install pdfarranger
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

PDF hasn't been proprietary since 2008. If you're paying money for a basic PDF editor, you're probably getting ripped off.

I recommend LibreOffice. In particular, LibreOffice Draw lets you edit and author PDF files like a typical word processor.

LibreOffice is included in Ubuntu repositories and it is both free (as in beer) and free (as in freedom).  To install it, run:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install libreoffice
```

Comment: LibreOffice messes up the fonts

Answer (score 1):

I suggest okular developed by KDE community. You can install it from Ubuntu app store or simply using apt package manager.

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt install -y okular
```

Answer (score 0):

Code Industry offers Master PDF Editor, which is free of charge for basic editing, but inserts a watermark for certain advanced editing.  The Pro version costs $70 and of course it doesn't insert watermarks.

https://code-industry.net/get-masterpdfeditor/

It's not OSS.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try okular PDF editor made by KDE community I am using it it's best I think