# Seeking PDF Reader for Linux with Translation, Highlighting, Note-taking, and Pen Writing Capabilities

Tags: software-recommendation, pdf

Hello Ubuntu Community,

I'm currently in search of a comprehensive PDF reader for my Linux system that offers a range of functionalities beyond basic reading. Specifically, I'm looking for a PDF reader that provides the following features:

Translation: The ability to translate words or phrases within the PDF document, particularly those highlighted for easy access to translations.

Highlighting: A feature that allows me to highlight important text within the PDF for better organization and reference.

Note-taking: Capability to add notes directly onto the PDF document, enabling me to jot down thoughts, comments, or reminders.

Pen Writing: The option to write directly onto the PDF using a pen tool or similar functionality for annotation purposes.

I've been exploring various PDF readers available for Linux but haven't yet found one that encompasses all these features. If anyone in the community knows of such an application or has recommendations for achieving these functionalities through a combination of tools, I'd greatly appreciate your insights and suggestions.

Thank you in advance for your assistance!

Comment: [This](https://askubuntu.com/q/1402159/730458) may be helpful.